# What are the HTML entities for up and down triangles?

Tags: html, entity

I've found the outlined versions, but I want the solid up and down triangles.

Does anyone know these entities?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

All named [HTML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) are specified in chapter 24 of the HTML standard. The only thing missing from the page are rendered entities, but you can easily create your own copy with the additional information by applying a simple regexp:

```
s/&lt;!ENTITY (\S+)/&lt;!ENTITY \1 &\1;/
```

Not all entities are named. For many, you need to specify the Unicode code page, either in decimal (&#9650; ▲, &#9660; ▼) or hex (&#x25B2; ▲, &#x25BC; ▼).

Comment: No, the ones that are solid and look like a triangle or an upside down triangle. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: For completeness, the decimal for ▼ is `&#9660;`.

Answer (score 46):

A little but late, but you can use `&blacktriangledown;` ▾, and `&blacktriangle;` ▴, to make both the up and down filled in triangles. I was looking for it myself and the alt codes didn't help so I decided to share this. This same thing works for both left and right as well.

Comment: Note that these don't seem to be supported in IE 9, not sure about other IE versions.

Comment: they also appear to be different sizes

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't know if I've ever seen what you're looking for.  Maybe a better way of doing it would be to create the arrows in Photoshop on a transparent background (.gif or .png format), and then load up the images.</strike>

Check that, you can do it through alt characters.
http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/ALTchrc.html

▼ ▲

Comment: Sure, the OP asked for HTML entities, and you suggested using an image (not answering the question) or Windows-centric alt codes (which are not guaranteed to look correct in the browser, and presume the OP is developing using Windows.)

Comment: Those Alt codes look just fine on my Mac as well. I was merely offering an alternative to entities if the OP could not find exactly what they were looking for. I then proceeded to dig a little bit to ensure I wasn't giving false info... notice the edit.

Comment: @ghoppe: sometimes the best answer isn't what someone asks for. Sometimes images are preferable to entities, especially when you take differences between fonts into account. @rockinthesixstring: however, what the OP asking for (in this case) is doable, and probably the best answer.

Answer (score -3):

using the alt characaters on your computer keyboard is a big no no if you are working on a web  page for many reasons. #1. encoding of the website, encoding of the database driving the website if any, the codepage of the computer view the website, the codepage your own pc's keyboard is set to.. all that are mostly factors you can not control. So some people will see wonky weird letter combos or sqiggle characters instead of what you intend. For webpages use the html codes for those characters when ever you can. or at least entity encode and make sure you have your code page defined in your html header of your site.. that way people will see what you intend them to.

now if you are doing this in word for a document that will be viewed in your own country you are probably safe. But for online things (site coding or data entry) you should avoid this like the plague.